# A model for melting and for weaving or interweaving?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I would like to know whether there are mathematical models for the processes of melting (like an ice-cream melting on the biscuit rather than snow) and weaving (or interweaving). If so, of what kind?
If you need more specification, please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For weaving, braid groups come to mind. I don't think they exist because of weaving, but it's a similar construct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And for melting? I have just seen that it was Emil Artin who started with braid theory in 1925. Does his work on the matter somehow relate to his reciprocity?

Comment: I don't know either of those things, unfortunately. I was just passing along something that seemed potentially relevant.

Comment: A friend of mine has just suggested the Navier-Stokes equations could fo it for the modelling of melting....Is he right?